# Spring 4 - Autowire generic interface

Tags: java, spring, generics, autowired

Starting with Spring (v4.3.8), I encounter a problem when Spring try to load dependency injections.

I want to call the "manage" method of the ManagerImpl1.java or ManagerImpl2.java implementation based on the type of T (Debit1 or Debit2). Here are the details:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.xxx.xxx.datacollection.infoprod.Manager'
>   available: expected single matching bean but found 2:
>   ManagerImpl1,ManagerImpl2

Business.java :

```
@Component
public class Business<T extends Debit> {

    @Autowired
    private Manager<T> manager;

    public void treatment(Context<T> context, FindServiceReturnMessage response) {

        manager.manage(response, context);
    }
```

Manager.java :

```
public interface Manager<T extends Debit> {

    void manage(final FindServiceReturnMessage response, Context<T> context);
}
```

ManagerImpl1.java :

```
@Component
public class ManagerImpl1 implements Manager<Debit1> {

    @Override
    public void manage(final FindServiceReturnMessage response, Context<Debit1> context) {

    }
}
```

ManagerImpl2.java :

```
@Component
public class ManagerImpl2 implements Manager<Debit2> {

    @Override
    public void manage(final FindServiceReturnMessage response, Context<Debit2> context) {

    }
}
```

Also, "Debit1" and "Debit2" implement the interface "Debit".

I tried several things but without success...

Comment: Generics are not present during runtime so they make no sense when they are used on `Autowired` objects.
If you want to have multiple beans that need to be injected via the same interface, checkout the `@Qualifier` annotation.

Comment: @Dvorog : Thank you for your reply. I understand what you said and I already try to add the `@Qualifier` annotation like that:

@Autowired
@Qualifier("ManagerImpl2")
private Manager<T> manager;

However, this code will always implement ManagerImpl2 and not ManagerImpl1

Comment: Well that is the point. The dependencies are injected only once (during the bean creation) and you should not change their implementation after the initialization of the spring context. How would you like to decide which bean to inject?
If you want to get a bean based on some business logic, maybe you should checkout the `ApplicationContext.getBean()` method. The problem with this approach is that you are no longer using IOC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a qualifier on your Bean like the following:

```
@Component
@Qualifier("managerImpl2")
public class ManagerImpl2 implements Manager<Debit2> {

    @Override
    public void manage(final FindServiceReturnMessage response, Context<Debit2> context) 
    {

    }
}
```

Then, when you wanna use it, use once more your `@Qualifier` annotation:

```
@Component
public class Business<T extends Debit> {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("managerImpl2")
    private Manager<T> manager;

    public void treatment(Context<T> context, FindServiceReturnMessage response) {

        manager.manage(response, context);
    }
}
```

Yet, as @dvorog said in the comments, as Generics are not present at compile, you will probably have to make a Business interface like this:

```
public interface Business<T extends Debit> {

    public void treatment(Context<T> context, FindServiceReturnMessage response);
}
```

and implements BusinessImpl to specify it each time you have a new kind of `Debit`:

```
@Component
public class ManagerImpl2Business<Debit2> {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("managerImpl2")
    private Manager<Debit2> manager;

    public void treatment(Context<Debit2> context, FindServiceReturnMessage response) {

        manager.manage(response, context);
    }
}
```

This will repeat a step over and will probably end with some unmaintainable code, or some `if (T instanceof Debit1)` somewhere to make your genericity work.